# Function to get style called repeatedly - Angular OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, polyline-creation, angular

I have a functionality where I can modify a polyline by dragging its coordinates over the map. In order to visually separate it from untouched polylines, I apply a new style when creating the selection. I noticed that the function to return this style is called repeatedly, on every interaction with selection (hover, drag...) . Is this actually OK? As a long time Angular developer I find this behavior a sign of an incorrect implementation.

```typescript
// Dynamic selection creation
private _initSelection(): void {
  this.selectInstance = new Select({
    condition: (mapBrowserEvent) => (this.hasFeature() ? false : click(mapBrowserEvent)),
    style: (feature) => getModifyFeatureLineStyle(feature),
    hitTolerance: MAP_CONSTANTS.HIT_TOLERANCE,
    filter: (feature) => feature.getProperties()['modelType'] === EntityType.SegmentEntity
  });

  this.selectInstance.on('select', (event: SelectEvent) => this.onPolylineSelected(event));

  this.mapService.registerInteraction(this.selectInstance);
}

// Style function
export function getModifyFeatureLineStyle(feature: FeatureLike) {
  // console.log('getModifyFeatureLineStyle') - can be called hundreds of times when modifying the line
  if (feature.getGeometry()?.getType() === 'LineString') {
    return new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: 'Crimson',
        width: 4
      }),
      fill: new Fill({
        color: 'Crimson'
      })
    });
  } else return undefined;
}
```

Does it have something to do with the way how `Select` is created or is it more of an issue of the super paranoid `getModifyFeatureLineStyle` function? This function is a part of the code I inherited and I'm wondering if it even necessary. Isn't it better just to return the style? I believe that the `Select` filters the feature type already.

Comment: Style functions are intended to let you set a feature specific properties of a style as in
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html 
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-label-decluttering.html 
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/street-labels.html and not to create new styles.  If you must create new styles use a cache as in  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html